# The use of the phrasal verb "take up" in context

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Does the use of *take up* sound correct and natural in the following sentence?

> When I was at school, I took so many notes that sometimes they **took up** a few dozens of pages.

Would it be better to say the following?

> When I was at school, I took so many notes that sometimes **they were
>   a few dozens pages long**.

If neither sounds ok, what would you say?

Comment: My bad! I meant "took notes". Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Your *took up* sounds fine to me, although the end part would be more natural to my (Br.Eng) ear as *took up a few dozen pages*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either of those ways of phrasing things is fine.  In particular, your use of "took up" there is entirely correct.

One side-note I would make:  When using phrases like "a few dozen", if it's made plural (with an "s" on the end), it can only be used as a noun.  When grouped-quantities like this are used as an adjective, you need to use a non-plural phrasing.  So this would be ok, because you're using "of":

> there were several dozens of eggs

But this needs to leave off the "s" in order to act as an adjective (and directly modify the noun):

> there were a few dozen pages

Also, idiomatically, people will pretty much always say "a few dozen *(somethings)*", rather than "a few dozens of *(something)*", but that's something that I think is kinda specific to the phrase "a few dozen" in particular.